# Как удалить сообщения в канале, если у пользователя есть роль?

Tags: node.js, discord

Хочу сделать так, что если у кого-то имеется роль `Clear`, удалялись все сообщения в чате при написании одной команды.

Код:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const roles = ['<Clear>'];

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot is ready`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            type: 'WATCHING',
            name: '',
        },
    });
});

client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.content.toLowerCase() == '!mute-chat') {
    for (role of roles) {
 if (message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.name === role))
    async function wipe() {
        var msg_size = 100;
        while (msg_size == 100) {
            await msg.channel.bulkDelete(100)
        .then(messages => msg_size = messages.size)
        .catch(console.error);
        }    
    wipe()
    }
    }
    }

});

client.login('секрет');
```

Ошибка:

```
D:\bot-vk-js\discord.js\test.js:20
        async function wipe() {
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Async functions can only be declared at the top level or inside a b
lock.
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js
:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать так:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const roles = ['<Clear>'];

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot is ready`);
  client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'online',
    activity: {
      type: 'WATCHING',
      name: '',
    },
  });
});

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() == '!mute-chat') {
    if (msg.member.roles.cache.some((r) => roles.includes(r.name))) {
      wipeChannel(msg.channel)
        .then(() => console.log('wipe ok'))
        .catch((err) => console.log('wipe fail', err));
    }
  }
});

async function wipeChannel(channel) {
  let deleted;
  do {
    deleted = await channel.bulkDelete(100, true);
  } while (deleted.size != 0);
}

client.login('секрет');
```